# Support for TouchID test on Detox framework

Tags: ios, react-native, touch-id, detox, earlgrey

I want to know if there is a way to test Touch ID with detox.

I mean, simulate success and failure and interactions with system alerts binding to the process.

Comment: You can always use search by text.

Comment: Yes, i tried to manage the system alerts, searching by text. But with not luck. Thanks anyway

Comment: You can tap an element `tap()` "Simulate tap on an element." https://github.com/wix/detox/blob/master/docs/APIRef.ActionsOnElement.md#tap

Comment: This seems possible in the simulator somehow. Could you please open an issue for https://github.com/wix/AppleSimulatorUtils and I will try to investigate.

Comment: sure, i can do it. But i think that this need to be on [github.com/wix/detox](https://github.com/wix/detox) and [github.com/wix/AppleSimulatorUtils](https://github.com/wix/AppleSimulatorUtils)  as well

Comment: I think I have found a way to add support for TouchID and FaceID in AppleSimUtils